# What's the purpose of VkStructureType?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm not very experienced with C++, so when I discovered that all structures in Vulkan API have a special field to pinpoint their type, I was pretty surprised:

> Any parameter that is a structure containing a VkStructureType::sType member must have a value of sType matching the type of the structure. As a general rule, the name of this value is obtained by taking the structure name, stripping the leading Vk, prefixing each capital letter with _, converting the entire resulting string to upper case, and prefixing it with VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_. For example, structures of type VkImageCreateInfo must have a sType value of VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO.

What functionality relies on this field? Can't it rely on facilities built into the language?

Comment: I suspect that his question could be rephrased so it would be about this C++ pattern in general, and not about Vulkan, but I don't think I know enough about it to do it. If you do - welcome.

Comment: Vulkan is a C API. It cannot use C++ features.

Comment: Damn. Reading C++ Vulkan tutorial, completely missed this. Feeling very stupid. However, this perfectly answers my question; feel free to make it an answer.